# Wolfram|Alpha Plotting multiple geometric objects

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to use WoflramAlpha to plot several gemoetries at once. It works fine up to an extent but after I add three different geometries to draw it just says it doesn't understand and picks something random from within my query to try and render.

My query is:

```
circle through (54,5) and (30,-5) centre (42, 0); line through (54,5) and (30,-5); x=54
```

It last worked before I added `x=54`. I tried separating each plot with semi-colons instead of commas but that didn't work either. I want to show a line through X=54 too, so I can create a triangle (I'm doing Mohr's Circles and using Wolfram to generate my graphs).

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be typical for Wolfram|Alpha; even grouping things with parentheses doesn't help; it seems to be so focussed on recognizing fuzzy queries that it doesn't realize when you're giving it a perfectly structured, automatically parseable string with proper delimiters. There should be an option to turn off all the guessing and force it to pay attention to formal structure.

Comment: Yeah, generally I can convince it to parse it properly by running each query separately and then copying what it gives as the 'input query', but you're just guessing how they're going to look at your query in this case. Yes I think it is a matter of their lexical engine is too fuzzy by default and I don't think we can change this.

Comment: @deed02392, migrate to mathematica.stackexchange

Comment: @alancalvitti: no. I've just checked with the Mathematica.SE mods, questions on Wolfram|Alpha are off-topic over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have realised that WolframAlpha does not like being asked to do multipe queries, even if you separate them properly. Instead I just had a lightbulb moment. If I derive the equations for the objects I wish to plot, I can feed them all to WolframAlpha in one query like so:

```
plot {x=100, x=-60, x=480, y=(83/19)x-(24070/19)}
```

This always seems to work and I've used up to 6 different objects to be returned in one graph. One limitation is the produced graph is pretty small, because the listing of the equations plotted shrinks the graph size, so it's not particularly useful unless you have Pro and can interactively resize it afterwards.